# How big of an image do I need if it will be used as an iPhone app's background cover?

Tags: android, ios, image

Suppose I want to make something where an image covers up most or all of the app's background, like this:

http://www.useronboard.com/how-slingshot-onboards-new-users/?slide=12

What is the minimum dimensions I would need? I know you need to get a higher resolution with iPhone apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends upon device/orientation for which you want to do so ideally it should not be less than screen resolution of that device.
For example: iPhone 6 display resolution is 1334x750 so you need image of that size to avoid any pixlation or disturbed aspect ratio issue.

Comment: There are also Android phones running at 1440 x 2560, and tablets at 2,560 x 1,600.  One possible issue with Android is different devices have different aspect ratios, so you may need to adjust settings on the image view to get the effect you want.  Test on emulators with different screen sizes and ratios.